# Can I ask a question about the best way to use an HTML-based interface in a standalone app here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've always written my interfaces in the language's native components (Forms in VB/VC#/VC++, Swing/JavaFX in Java, HTML+CSS+JS in webpages, etc.), but with my next project I want to try writing the interface in HTML+CSS and making objects in that document call C++ code. When typing up my question, though, I couldn't figure out which SE was best, if any. **Is it on-topic to ask about this here?**

---

I feel like it'd help to show you exactly what I'm asking, so here's the question I drafted:

> I'm looking to make a native application, and want to dabble in making the interface in HTML (hopefully this will lead to more separation of tasks and easier updating). I know that you can do this in Windows web forms with a browser object, but **I'd like this to be more cross-platform friendly** <sub>(aside: is that reasonable? Or is it separable enough to write a whole new program for Windows/OS X/X Window/etc. and just use another native browser object?)</sub>, so I was thinking of using AppJS (which has a NodeJS backbone), or maybe embedding Gecko or Blink into a window, or even forking Firefox or Chromium and stripping it down to its barebones. **Which one, if any, of these approaches is best, and why? If none, what is?** Of course, I'll need the HTML controls to call native code somehow.

Comment: Recommended reading: [**What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau thanks! Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my question?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is if we can tell you which user interface design pattern and languages to use for your project.  There are a great many options (just looking at .Net for example you frequently see MVP, MVC and MVVM) which you could deploy to a machine by installing a local copy of the webserver of your choice with your application if you wanted to use html/css.

This is still a "what language should I use" question which make it unsuitable for StackExchange generally as any answers are likely to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: thanks! Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my question?